# Problemas ao enviar FILE para a Base de dados

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

Estou com um problema ao enviar dados FILE para a BD.
Com a ajuda do @zuul cheguei a este problema.

```
<?php

require("conectar.php"); //chama o arquivo de conexão ao BD

if (isset($_POST['Nome'])) {
    $Nome = $_POST['Nome'];
}

$Morada = $_POST['Morada'];
$Tipo = $_POST['Tipo'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$AlvaraNumero = $_POST['AlvaraNumero'];
$AlvaraValidade = $_POST['AlvaraValidade'];
$AlvaraAnexo = '';

if (isset($_FILES["AlvaraAnexo"]) && $_FILES["AlvaraAnexo"]["name"] != '') {

    $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["AlvaraAnexo"]["tmp_name"];

    $fp = fopen($nomeTemporario, 'r');
    $AlvaraAnexo = fread($fp, filesize($nomeTemporario));
    $AlvaraAnexo = addslashes($AlvaraAnexo);
    print_r($_FILES);
    fclose($fp);
}

$AcidenteNumero = $_POST['AcidenteNumero'];
$AcidenteValidade = $_POST['AcidenteValidade'];
$AcidenteAnexo = $_POST['AcidenteAnexo'];
$SeguroNumero = $_POST['SeguroNumero'];
$SeguroValidade = $_POST['SeguroValidade'];
$SeguroAnexo = $_POST['SeguroAnexo'];
$FinancasValidade = $_POST['FinancasValidade'];
$FinancasAnexo = $_POST['FinancasAnexo'];
$SocialValidade = $_POST['SocialValidade'];
$SocialAnexo = $_POST['SocialAnexo'];
$RemuneracaoValidade = $_POST['RemuneracaoValidade'];
$RemuneracaoAnexo = $_POST['RemuneracaoAnexo'];
$InstaladorNumero = $_POST['InstaladorNumero'];
$InstaladorValidade = $_POST['InstaladorValidade'];
$InstaladorAnexo = $_POST['InstaladorAnexo'];
$MontadorNumero = $_POST['MontadorNumero'];
$MontadorValidade = $_POST['MontadorValidade'];
$MontadorAnexo = $_POST['MontadorAnexo'];

print_r($_FILES);

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tb_trabalhador  VALUES(0,'" . $Nome . "','" . $Morada . "','" . $Tipo . "','" . $Email . "','" . $AlvaraNumero . "','" . $AlvaraValidade . "','" . $AlvaraAnexo . "', '" . $AcidenteNumero . "', '" . $AcidenteValidade . "','" . $AcidenteAnexo . "','" . $SeguroNumero . "','" . $SeguroValidade . "','" . $SeguroAnexo . "','" . $FinancasValidade . "','" . $FinancasAnexo . "','" . $SocialValidade . "','" . $SocialAnexo . "','" . $RemuneracaoValidade . "','" . $RemuneracaoAnexo . "','" . $InstaladorNumero . "','" . $InstaladorValidade . "','" . $InstaladorAnexo . "','" . $MontadorNumero . "','" . $MontadorValidade . "','" . $MontadorAnexo . "')";
mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die("Não foi possível inserir os dados");
?>
```

Nessa linha:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

... aparecem os arquivos:

```
Array (
    [AlvaraAnexo] => Array (
        [name] => cc2.pdf
        [type] => application/pdf
        [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpFE7C.tmp
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 153613
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Qual o tipo de campo no banco de dados para a variável do file? `Blob`ou `Text`? E o que a variável `$AlvaraAnexo` está imprimindo?

Comment: dados blob para todos os campos anexo. é o que uso

Comment: Tenta da um `print_r($_FILES["AlvaraAnexo"])`. Porque está retornando dados do FILES e nao as variáveis inseridas do arquivo.

Answer (score 4):

O output da matriz `$_FILES` está a sair com a seguinte informação:

```php
Array (
  [AlvaraAnexo] => Array (
    [name]     => cc2.pdf                   // nome do teu ficheiro
    [type]     => application/pdf           // header detectado
    [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpFE7C.tmp   // localização e nome temporário
    [error]    => 0                         // Erro código 0 é o mesmo que tudo correu bem
    [size]     => 153613                    // tamanho do ficheiro
  ) 
)
```

Isso diz-nos que no que respeita ao formulário em HTML, envio do ficheiro e aceitação do mesmo por parte do servidor, tudo está a correr como esperado.

Se quiseres saber mais sobre outros códigos de erro, podes visitar a página da documentação do PHP: [Mensagens de erro explicadas](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> onde constam os diversos valores que podes receber em `$_FILES["AlvaraAnexo"]["error"]`.

---

Assim sendo, podemos então pegar no teu ficheiro que está com determinado nome temporário, ler o mesmo para uma variável e inserir na base de dados.

Isto requer uma série de passos de verificação para garântir que está tudo a ser realizado como é suposto. Como não estás com precisão a indicar onde poderá estar localizado o teu problema, vou tentar cobrir todos os passos do processo assumindo já o que disse em cima (erro com código 0 = ficheiro carregado com sucesso para o servidor.):

1. Verificar a matriz de ficheiros

   Antes de iniciarmos operações com a matriz de ficheiros, convém verificar se a mesma está presente, se a entrada que pretendemos existe e se não existiram erros:

   ```php
   // Variáveis de controlo
   $campoForm = "AlvaraAnexo";
   $mensagemErro = "";

   // verificar se existe a matriz $_FILES
   if (isset($_FILES)) {

     // verificar se existe a entrada com o nome do nosso campo no formulário HTML
     if (isset($_FILES[$campoForm])) {

       // verificar se a entrada "error" contém o valor 0
       if ($_FILES[$campoForm]["error"]==0) {
         /* tudo OK, vamos continuar
          */
       } else {

         switch($_FILES[$campoForm]["error"]) {
           case 1: {
             $mensagemErro = "O arquivo enviado excede a directiva upload_max_filesize no php.ini.";
             break;
           }
           case 2: {
             $mensagemErro = "O arquivo enviado excede a directiva MAX_FILE_SIZE que foi especificado no formulário HTML.";
             break;
           }
           case 3: {
             $mensagemErro = "O arquivo foi apenas parcialmente carregado.";
             break;
           }
           case 4: {
             $mensagemErro = "Nenhum arquivo enviado.";
             break;
           }
           case 6: {
             $mensagemErro = "Faltando uma pasta temporária.";
             break;
           }
           case 7: {
             $mensagemErro = "Falha ao gravar o arquivo no disco.";
             break;
           }
           case 8: {
             $mensagemErro = "Uma extensão do PHP parou o upload dos arquivos.";
             break;
           }
           default: {
             $mensagemErro = "Erro desconhecido com o código:".$_FILES[$campoForm]["error"];
             break;
           }
         }
       }
     } else {
       $mensagemErro = "Não foi possível encontrar na matriz de ficheiros a entrar para o campo ".$campoForm.".";
     }
   } else {
     $mensagemErro = "Não foi possível encontrar a matriz de ficheiros!";
   }

   // verifica se temos erros antes de continuar
   if (!empty($mensagemErro))
     die($mensagemErro);
   ```
2. Verificar o ficheiro temporário

   Para podermos utilizar o ficheiro, no teu caso ler o conteúdo do mesmo para a base de dados, temos que verificar se o mesmo existe, se pode ser lido e se não está vazio:

   ```php
   // verifica sem temos o caminho e nome do ficheiro
   if (!empty($_FILES[$campoForm]["tmp_name"])) {

     $ficheiroTemp = $_FILES["AlvaraAnexo"]["tmp_name"];

     // verifica se o ficheiro existe no servidor
     if (is_file($ficheiroTemp)) {

       // verifica se o ficheiro pode ser lido
       if (is_readable($ficheiroTemp)) {

         /* se chegamos aqui, podemos iniciar a leitura do
          * ficheiro para uma variável e preparar os dados
          * lidos para inserção na base de dados
          */
         $fp = fopen($ficheiroTemp, 'r');
         $AlvaraAnexo = fread($fp, filesize($ficheiroTemp));
         $AlvaraAnexo = addslashes($AlvaraAnexo);
         fclose($fp);

       } else {
         $mensagemErro = "O ficheiro não pode ser lido!";
       }

     } else {
       $mensagemErro = "Ficheiro temporário não foi localizado no servidor!";
     }
   } else {
     $mensagemErro = "Nome temporário do ficheiro está vazio!";
   }
   ```

## Código final

Para te facilitar as coisas, envolvi o código que lida com o ficheiro numa função que te devolve o resultado da leitura do ficheiro ou o erro encontrado.

Uma única função está longe de ser a forma correcta para organizar o código, precisarias de várias ou mesmo uma classe para lidar com o *upload* do ficheiro, mas para não complicar muito as coisas:

```php
/**
 * Ler Ficheiro para Variavel
 * 
 * Ler o conteúdo de um ficheiro temporário
 * que acabou de ser carregado para o servidor
 * para uma variabel de forma a ser guardado
 * na base de dados.
 * 
 * @param array $fileArr            Matriz $_FILES
 * @param string $campoForm         Nome do campo no formulário
 * 
 * @return mix string|array         Matriz com mensagem de erro ou ficheiro
 */
function lerFicheiroParaVariavel($fileArr, $campoForm = '') {

// Variáveis de controlo
$mensagemErro = "";

    // verificar se existe a matriz $_FILES
    if (isset($fileArr) && is_array($fileArr)) {

      // verificar se existe a entrada com o nome do nosso campo no formulário HTML
      if (isset($fileArr[$campoForm])) {

        // verificar se a entrada "error" contém o valor 0
        if ($fileArr[$campoForm]["error"]==0) {
          /* tudo OK, vamos continuar
           */
        } else {

          $erro = $fileArr[$campoForm]["error"];

          switch($erro) {
            case 1: {
              $mensagemErro = "O arquivo enviado excede a directiva upload_max_filesize no php.ini.";
              break;
            }
            case 2: {
              $mensagemErro = "O arquivo enviado excede a directiva MAX_FILE_SIZE que foi especificado no formulário HTML.";
              break;
            }
            case 3: {
              $mensagemErro = "O arquivo foi apenas parcialmente carregado.";
              break;
            }
            case 4: {
              $mensagemErro = "Nenhum arquivo enviado.";
              break;
            }
            case 6: {
              $mensagemErro = "Faltando uma pasta temporária.";
              break;
            }
            case 7: {
              $mensagemErro = "Falha ao gravar o arquivo no disco.";
              break;
            }
            case 8: {
              $mensagemErro = "Uma extensão do PHP parou o upload dos arquivos.";
              break;
            }
            default: {
              $mensagemErro = "Erro desconhecido com o código:".$erro;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        $mensagemErro = "Não foi possível encontrar na matriz de ficheiros a entrar para o campo ".$campoForm.".";
      }
    } else {
      $mensagemErro = "Não foi possível encontrar a matriz de ficheiros!";
    }


    // verifica se temos erros antes de continuar
    if (!empty($mensagemErro))
      return array("erro" => $mensagemErro);


    // verifica sem temos o caminho e nome do ficheiro
    if (!empty($fileArr[$campoForm]["tmp_name"])) {

      $ficheiroTemp = $fileArr["AlvaraAnexo"]["tmp_name"];

      // verifica se o ficheiro existe no servidor
      if (is_file($ficheiroTemp)) {

        // verifica se o ficheiro pode ser lido
        if (is_readable($ficheiroTemp)) {

          /* se chegamos aqui, podemos iniciar a leitura do
           * ficheiro para uma variável e preparar os dados
           * lidos para inserção na base de dados
           */
          $fp = fopen($ficheiroTemp, 'r');
          $AlvaraAnexo = fread($fp, filesize($ficheiroTemp));
          $AlvaraAnexo = addslashes($AlvaraAnexo);
          fclose($fp);

          return $AlvaraAnexo;

        } else {
          $mensagemErro = "O ficheiro não pode ser lido!";
        }
      } else {
        $mensagemErro = "Ficheiro temporário não foi localizado no servidor!";
      }
    } else {
      $mensagemErro = "Nome temporário do ficheiro está vazio!";
    }

    // se chegamos aqui é porque temos um erro, vamos devolver o mesmo
    return array("erro" => $mensagemErro);
}
```

Para utilizares a função, coloca a mesma no início do teu ficheiro e aplica este código no local onde estás a ler o ficheiro.

Onde tens:

```php
if (isset($_FILES["AlvaraAnexo"]) && $_FILES["AlvaraAnexo"]["name"] != '') {
  ...
}
```

Apaga todo o `if` *statment* e troca por isto, onde ou tens um erro a dar-te conta do que se passa ou tens a variável `$AlvaraAnexo` contendo o conteúdo do ficheiro carregado.

```php
/* verifica se temos a matriz de ficheiros
 * e se sim procedemos à leitura do ficheiro,
 * caso não recolhemos a mensagem de erro
 */
if (isset($_FILES)) {
    $ficheiro = lerFicheiroParaVariavel($_FILES, "AlvaraAnexo");

    if (is_array($ficheiro)) {
        $mensagemErro = $ficheiro["erro"];
    } else {
        $AlvaraAnexo = $ficheiro;
    }
} else {
    $mensagemErro = "Não foi possível encontrar a matriz de ficheiros!";
}

if (!empty($mensagemErro))
    die($mensagemErro);
```

**Nota:** Isto lida com um ficheiro carregado pelo campo `name="AlvaraAnexo"`, mas o processo deve ser repetido para todos os ficheiros que estão a ser carregados.

---

## Base de Dados

Relativamente à questão da base de dados, é preciso verificar se as consultas de inserção estão a ocorrer, se a tabela está bem configurada e se os campos estão a ser preenchidos com alguma coisa:

1. Estrutura da tabela

   Os teus campos que recebem documentos PDF devem estar todos no formato `blob`.

   Além disso, é preciso ter em conta o tamanho dos dados a serem guardados:

   - `BLOB` pode ter até 65535 bytes no máximo;
   - `MEDIUMBLOB` pode ter até 16777215 bytes no máximo;
   - `LONGBLOB` pode ter até 4294967295 bytes no máximo.

   **Uma advertência:** Armazenar diversos `blob` na bases de dados não é geralmente considerado a melhor ideia, pois pode causar `bloat` <sup>[inchaço](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/data-size.html) (Inglês)</sup> à tabela, tendo também uma série de outros problemas associados.

   A melhor solução para o teu caso dado estares a trabalhar diversos ficheiros seria mover os mesmos para uma pasta e guardar apenas o caminho para os mesmos na base de dados.
2. Consulta de inserção

   Deverás proteger os dados que o utilizador te deu antes dos enviares para a base de dados. Para isso podes fazer uso do [mysql_real_escape_string](http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> para preparares a tua consulta:

   ```php
   // Preparar a consulta de inserção
   $sqlinsert = sprintf(
       "INSERT INTO tb_trabalhador VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
       mysql_real_escape_string(null),
       mysql_real_escape_string($Nome),
       mysql_real_escape_string($Morada),
       mysql_real_escape_string($Tipo),
       mysql_real_escape_string($Email),
       mysql_real_escape_string($AlvaraNumero),
       mysql_real_escape_string($AlvaraValidade),
       mysql_real_escape_string($AlvaraAnexo),
       mysql_real_escape_string($AcidenteNumero),
       mysql_real_escape_string($AcidenteValidade),
       mysql_real_escape_string($AcidenteAnexo),
       mysql_real_escape_string($SeguroNumero),
       mysql_real_escape_string($SeguroValidade),
       mysql_real_escape_string($SeguroAnexo),
       mysql_real_escape_string($FinancasValidade),
       mysql_real_escape_string($FinancasAnexo),
       mysql_real_escape_string($SocialValidade),
       mysql_real_escape_string($SocialAnexo),
       mysql_real_escape_string($RemuneracaoValidade),
       mysql_real_escape_string($RemuneracaoAnexo),
       mysql_real_escape_string($InstaladorNumero),
       mysql_real_escape_string($InstaladorValidade),
       mysql_real_escape_string($InstaladorAnexo),
       mysql_real_escape_string($MontadorNumero),
       mysql_real_escape_string($MontadorValidade),
       mysql_real_escape_string($MontadorAnexo)
   );

   // tentar inserir dados na base de dados
   mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die("Não foi possível inserir os dados");
   ```

   **Nota:** Para cada `mysql_real_escape_string` deverá existir um `'%s'` na consulta. E para cada campo deverá existir um `mysql_real_escape_string`. Confirma tudo direitinho com os campos na tua tabela.

Comment: **Nota:** todo o código na resposta foi feito de cabeça, não tenho como o testar neste momento, mas deverá estar tudo OK. Contudo, coloca no início do teu ficheiro PHP o seguinte: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` para activares os erros e veres se falta algum `;` Avisa se precisares de mais ajuda, estou por aqui.