# Update dados File

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma duvida em alterar dados FILE.

```
<?php

include("conectar.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = mysql_query("Select* From tb_trabalhador WHERE id = $id");
while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

$id = $exibe["id"];

$Nome = $exibe["Nome"];

$Morada = $exibe["Morada"];

$Tipo = $exibe["Tipo"];

$Email = $exibe["Email"];

$AlvaraNumero = $exibe["AlvaraNumero"];

$AlvaraValidade = $exibe["AlvaraValidade"];

$AlvaraAnexo = $exibe["AlvaraAnexo"];
?>
<form action="salvaralteracao.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    Nome<input type="Varchar" name="Nome" value="<?php echo $Nome; ?>"><p>
    Morada<input type="Text" name="Morada" value="<?php echo $Morada; ?>"><p>
    Email<input type="text" name="Email" value="<?php echo $Email; ?>"><p>
    AlvaraNumero<input type="integer" name="AlvaraNumero" value="<?php echo   $AlvaraNumero; ?>"><p>
    AlvaraValidade<input type="date" name="AlvaraValidade" value="<?php echo   $AlvaraValidade; ?>"><p>
    <input type="hidden" name="AlvaraAnexo" value="<?php echo $AlvaraAnexo; ?>"><p>
```

Quando mostro isso aparece-me montes de simbolos devido aos Anexos (PDF que coloquei)

A forma de alterar isso mostrando os nomes dos dados dos anexos apenas?

Salvaralteracao.php

```
   <?php

  include("conectar.php");

  $id = $_POST['id'];

$Nome = $_POST['Nome'];

$Morada = $_POST['Morada'];

$Email = $_POST['Email'];

$AlvaraNumero = $_POST["AlvaraNumero"];

$AlvaraValidade = $_POST["AlvaraValidade"];

if (isset($_FILES[AlvaraAnexo]) && $_FILES[AlvaraAnexo]["name"]!=''){
$nomeTemporario = $_FILES["AlvaraAnexo"]["tmp_name"]; 

$fp = fopen($nomeTemporario, 'r'); 
$AlvaraAnexo = fread($fp, filesize($nomeTemporario)); 
$AlvaraAnexo = addslashes($AlvaraAnexo);

fclose($fp); }

$AcidenteNumero = $_POST["AcidenteNumero"];

$AcidenteValidade = $_POST["AcidenteValidade"];

if (isset($_FILES[AcidenteAnexo]) && $_FILES[AcidenteAnexo]["name"]!=''){

$nomeTemporario = $_FILES["AcidenteAnexo"]["tmp_name"]; 

$fp = fopen($nomeTemporario, 'r'); 
$AcidenteAnexo = fread($fp, filesize($nomeTemporario)); 
$AcidenteAnexo = addslashes($AcidenteAnexo);

fclose($fp)
    (...)
$sqlupdate = "Update tb_trabalhador SET Nome='$Nome',Morada='$Morada',Email='$Email',   AlvaraNumero='$AlvaraNumero',AlvaraValidade='$AlvaraValidade',AlvaraAnexo='$AlvaraAnexo',Aci    denteNumero='$AcidenteNumero',AcidenteValidade='$AcidenteValidade',
AcidenteAnexo='$AcidenteAnexo',SeguroNumero='$SeguroNumero',
 SeguroValidade='$SeguroValidade',SeguroAnexo='$SeguroAnexo',FinancasValidade='$FinancasValidade',
FinancasAnexo='$FinancasAnexo',SocialValidade='$SocialValidade',
SocialAnexo='$SocialAnexo',RemuneracaoValidade='$RemuneracaoValidade',
RemuneracaoAnexo='$RemuneracaoAnexo',InstaladorNumero='$InstaladorNumero',
InstaladorValidade='$InstaladorValidade',InstaladorAnexo='$InstaladorAnexo',
MontadorNumero='$MontadorNumero',MontadorValidade='$MontadorValidade',
MontadorAnexo='$MontadorAnexo' where id=$id ";

 mysql_query($sqlupdate) or die(mysql_error());header('Location: administrador.php');
```

?>

Comment: Parece que estás a criar um formulário para permitir que o utilizador realize alterações num registo da tua tabela. Se assim for, o mesmo vai poder trocar o documento? _(caso não, a minha sugestão seria que não tivesses esse campo escondido com o binário do PDF)_ Para actualizares um registo na base de dados não precisas mexer em todos os campos, podes mexer apenas nos que pretendes efectivamente alterar.

Comment: Se o utilizador tiver possibilidade de trocar o documento, mesmo assim poder-se-ia ajustar esse teu formulário para não ter esse campo escondido com o conteúdo do PDF. Tudo depende do objectivo que te está a levar a ter esse campo presente.

Comment: Assim como é possivel ter os outros campos para alterar os arquivos pdf tambem se podiam alterar. 
A minha ideia é dar hipótese de alterar todos os campos

Answer (score 1):

Para que possas apresentar um formulário com vista a serem alterados todos os campos de determinado registo numa tabela que contém colunas do tipo `BLOB` com documentos PDF presentes na mesma, deverás evitar os campos `input` do tipo `hidden` com o conteúdo do documento.

Podes contornar a situação apresentando um link para o documento existente de forma a que o utilizador possa consultar o mesmo. Aplicas também um campo `input` do tipo `file` para ser realizado o *upload* de um novo documento.

A minha sugestão passa então pela [criação de um ficheiro de PHP com o único objectivo de apresentar no navegador o documento PDF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5794/223) que pode ser referenciado da seguinte forma:

```php
<?php

/** Construir link para apresentação de anexo
 *
 * @param integer $id      O id do registo na base de dados
 * @param string $campo    O nome do campo que contém o BLOB a ser apresentado
 *
 * @return string $html    O HTML necessário para apresentar um link
 */
function apresentarLinkParaDocumento ($id, $campo) {

  $href = 'verdocumentos.php?id='.$id.'&amp;documento='.$campo;
  $title = 'Clique para abrir documento';

  $html = '
  <p>
    Visualizar documento existente: <a href="'.$href.'" target="_blank" title="'.$title.'">Clique aqui</a>
  </p>';

  return $html;
}
?>
```

Para ser utilizado:

```php
if ($AlvaraAnexo!='')
  $preview = apresentarLinkParaDocumento ($id, $AlvaraAnexo);
else 
  $preview = '';
```

E assim tens na variável `$preview` o HTML necessário para apresentar um link para o documento caso existam dados na tua variável `$AlvaraAnexo`. Se não existirem dados a mesma fica vazia, pelo que pode sempre ser utilizada.

No teu formulário, no local onde queres o link, aplicas a variável `$preview`:

```php
<form action="salvaralteracao.php" method="POST">
  <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    Nome<input type="Varchar" name="Nome" value="<?php echo $Nome; ?>">
  </p>
  <p>
    Morada<input type="Text" name="Morada" value="<?php echo $Morada; ?>">
  </p>
  <p>
    Email<input type="text" name="Email" value="<?php echo $Email; ?>">
  </p>
  <p>
    AlvaraNumero<input type="integer" name="AlvaraNumero" value="<?php echo   $AlvaraNumero; ?>">
  </p>
  <p>
    AlvaraValidade<input type="date" name="AlvaraValidade" value="<?php echo   $AlvaraValidade; ?>">
  </p>
  <p>
    <?php echo $preview; ?>
  </p>
  <!-- Continuação do formulário... -->
```

Depois tens então o `input` do tipo `file` [para que seja carregado um novo documento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/7909/223) e só tens que verificar se efectivamente existe um novo documento para substituir o conteúdo do campo na base de dados:

```
<input type="file" name="AlvaraAnexo">
```

Quando o formulário é submetido pelo utilizador:

```
// se foi enviado um novo ficheiro
if (isset($_FILES[AlvaraAnexo]) && $_FILES[AlvaraAnexo]["name"]!='') {

  // operações de ler ficheiro para variável

  // consulta à base de dados para actualizar a coluna para este ficheiro
  $consulta = "UPDATE tb_trabalhador SET AlvaraAnexo='$AlvaraAnexoBLOB' WHERE id=$id";

  mysql_query($consulta) or die(mysql_error());
}

// nesta altura o ficheiro novo já foi aplicado na base de dados em vez do antigo, e continuas agora com o resto da operação de actualização.
```

---

Existem duas coisas mencionadas nesta resposta que não elaborei por já terem sido discutidas em duas perguntas tuas anteriores:

- [Apresentar conteúdo de campo “longblob” que contém ficheiro PDF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5794/223)
- [Problemas ao enviar FILE para a Base de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7722/223)

---

## Actualização

A consulta para actualizar os dados deve ser manipulada no sentido de não mexer em colunas do tipo `BLOB` que estão a servir para guardar ficheiros na base de dados.

Para o efeito, e conforme em cima ilustrado, deverás realizar uma consulta para cada coluna do tipo `BLOB` quando a mesma recebeu um novo ficheiro a ser guardado na base de dados.

Em baixo a tua consulta final para as restantes colunas sem referência à coluna `AlvaraAnexo` do tipo `BLOB` que já foi manipulada conforme podemos ver na ilustração em cima apresentada:

```
/* Removi a linha: "AlvaraAnexo = '$AlvaraAnexo',"
 * Pois essa coluna é actualizada quando verificamos se existe um novo ficheiro
 *
 * Deverás proceder da mesma forma para as restantes
 * colunas do tipo BLOB que guardam um ficheiro
 */
$sqlupdate = "
UPDATE tb_trabalhador 
SET
    Nome = '$Nome',
    Morada = '$Morada',
    Email = '$Email',
    AlvaraNumero = '$AlvaraNumero',
    AlvaraValidade = '$AlvaraValidade',
    AcidenteNumero = '$AcidenteNumero',
    AcidenteValidade = '$AcidenteValidade',
    AcidenteAnexo = '$AcidenteAnexo',
    SeguroNumero = '$SeguroNumero',
    SeguroValidade = '$SeguroValidade',
    SeguroAnexo = '$SeguroAnexo',
    FinancasValidade = '$FinancasValidade',
    FinancasAnexo = '$FinancasAnexo',
    SocialValidade = '$SocialValidade',
    SocialAnexo = '$SocialAnexo',
    RemuneracaoValidade = '$RemuneracaoValidade',
    RemuneracaoAnexo = '$RemuneracaoAnexo',
    InstaladorNumero = '$InstaladorNumero',
    InstaladorValidade = '$InstaladorValidade',
    InstaladorAnexo = '$InstaladorAnexo',
    MontadorNumero = '$MontadorNumero',
    MontadorValidade = '$MontadorValidade',
    MontadorAnexo = '$MontadorAnexo'
WHERE id=$id";

mysql_query($sqlupdate) or die(mysql_error());
header('Location: administrador.php');
```

Comment: Colocando para ver os anexos e colocando o Botão para carregar os dados desaparecem . Passando de Blob para nulos

Comment: @user3253195 Para os dados desaparecem, é porque na consulta à base de dados para actualizar os mesmos estás a enviar `null` ou uma variável vazia. Deverás realizar uma consulta para actualizar todos os campos menos os dos ficheiros. Os dos ficheiros deverão ser actualizados apenas se o utilizador carregou um novo ficheiro, conforme ilustrei na resposta.

Comment: Boas Zuul. Não entendi muito bem a primeiro Function.
Tenho já um ficheiro que mostra os PDF's. 
Na mesma pagina coloco: <?php echo $preview; ?><input type="file" name="AlvaraAnexo"> Na mesma linha correcto?

Comment: @user3253195 A função `apresentarLinkParaDocumento()` serve para preparar o HTML para apresentar um link para o documento. Deverás alterar a construção do link dentro da mesma para que se adapte ao teu cenário. Relativamente à forma como apresentas no formulário, vai depender do teu layout, mas como estás a sugerir resulta sim.

Comment: Só estou a ter problema porque eles todos passam a NULL e não sei porque.
if (isset($_FILES[AlvaraAnexo]) && $_FILES[AlvaraAnexo]["name"]!='') { tenho este codigo na guardar alteração e eles mesmo assim ficam como null.

Comment: @user3253195 Só vendo esse teu ficheiro onde estás a fazer a consulta à base de dados é que consigo ver o problema. Para passarem a `NULL` para a base de dados só pode ser porque estás a mexer nessa coluna em particular quer tenha existido novo upload quer não tenha.

Comment: Inventei agora um pouco e não sei se é assim o Salvaralteração.php

Comment: @user3253195 Como dizia à pouco, penso que o teu problema está na consulta de actualização... A consulta tem que ignorar os campos com `BLOB` cujos mesmos não foram alterados, ou seja, se não foi enviado novo ficheiro para guardar, a consulta não pode mexer nesse campo. Como dizes que fica a `NULL`, parece-me que estás a mexer no campo ao actualizar quer existam dados quer não. Coloca a parte da consulta de actualização na tua pergunta, vendo a mesma poderei ajudar mais.

Comment: Coloquei a parte do update na pergunta.

Comment: @user3253195 Actualizei a resposta dando conta da tua consulta final. Actualizei também a parte onde verificas se o ficheiro existe para deixar a consulta que actualiza a coluna do ficheiro de acordo com a tua realidade.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o [PDF Parser](http://www.pdfparser.org/) para fazer a conversão do arquivo PDF para texto.